# How can I calculate the total views of all the videos on a YouTube playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would like to add the view count of every video in a playlist.

Any way of doing this?

Example playlist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJQP7kiw5Fk&list=PL8A83124F1D79BD4F

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve YouTube videos ids from the YouTube playlist by using [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with `part=snippet` in `item["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"]` and then you can use [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with `part=statistics` to retrieve their view count in `item["statistics"]["viewCount"]` then sum them.